# how to disable other maven phases like we do with maven.test.skip=true?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

my first.

I am looking for a way to disable maven resource and jar plugin phases from command line specifically,
something like `-Dmaven.test.skip=true` which seems to disable *maven-surefire-plugin:version:test*

`-Dmaven.{jar,resource}.skip=true` kind of.

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For dependency plugin use `maven.resources.skip` [property](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/resources-mojo.html#skip).

Regarding maven jar plugin, it seems there is not a similar property, but in the links below you may find alternatives.

[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37722967/how-to-disable-jar-creation-in-commandline-in-a-maven-project) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188746/what-is-the-best-way-to-avoid-maven-jar)

Comment: This is what I was looking for,  the concern came while trying to improve build time since there's lots of modules with no resources, then took the moment to ask for other plugins as well. Thanks sir.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you cannot deactivate *phases*. You can only deactivate plugins. `-Dmaven.test.skip=true` does not deactivate the  `test` phase, but the surefire plugin.

Therefore, you need to check for the different plugins if they have a skip parameter. @leopal gave you the right directions.

Comment: Very helpful clarification. Thank you sir.